# C# Selenium Chrome automação, Como acessar uma HTMLCollection usando o selenium no visual studio

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-2019

Bem pessoal, estou tentando acessar um index de um HTML Collection pelo selenium no visual studio, so que não estou conseguindo acessar, estou utilizando o classname pra acessar um determinado campo, e buscar seu valor.

no console do chrome é tranquilo:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('xxxx')[numero]
```

E o numero vai de 0 a 7.

pelo selenium eu chego ate isso:

```
nav.FindElement(By.ClassName("xxxx"));
```

estou utilizando o C# pra fazer a automação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No singular pega um elemento:

```
nav.FindElement(By.ClassName("xxxx"));
```

No plural pega todos disponíveis:

```
nav.FindElements(By.ClassName("xxxx"));
```

Comment: Funcionou, agora esta acessando ok, mais uma duvida.
quando eu tento pega o valor do campo em questão com esse comando:
string valor = nav.FindElements(By.ClassName("x-combo-list-item"))[0].Text;
ele esta demorando muito para realizar a busca. e me traz uma lista ISeachContext com o total de index que tem minha coleção.

como eu faço pra ele buscar somente o valor do index em questão

Comment: @Romssnes pode estar demorando porque a página ainda não carregou. Eu uso Selenium com C# a um bom tempo e nunca tive problema de lentidão, só quando os sites acessados são lentos para carregar os primeiros elementos ou quando o site é muito mal feito, mas no geral é rapido.